# Why am I getting stack overflow error when splitting my code into different classes?

Tags: java

I recently made a Connect 4 game. However, I did all my code in a single Java file / class. I am now trying to refactor my code so that I split up different code operations into different classes. e.g. play, counter and board.

Could somebody explain to me why im getting the following errors?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.nio.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:201)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.<init>(ByteBuffer.java:281)
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.<init>(StreamDecoder.java:251)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.<init>(StreamDecoder.java:231)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(StreamDecoder.java:69)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:74)
at Connect4Game.<init>(Connect4Game.java:19)
at play.<init>(play.java:2)
at Connect4Game.<init>(Connect4Game.java:21)
at play.<init>(play.java:2)
at Connect4Game.<init>(Connect4Game.java:21)
at play.<init>(play.java:2)
at Connect4Game.<init>(Connect4Game.java:21)
at play.<init>(play.java:2)
at Connect4Game.<init>(Connect4Game.java:21)
at play.<init>(play.java:2)
at Connect4Game.<init>(Connect4Game.java:21)
at play.<init>(play.java:2)
at Connect4Game.<init>(Connect4Game.java:21)
at play.<init>(play.java:2)
at Connect4Game.<init>(Connect4Game.java:21)
at play.<init>(play.java:2)
```

Would really appreciate just being pointed in the right direction, as this is the first time I have refactored working code into multiple classes.

Here is my code:

**Connect4Game.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Connect4Game {

final int boardWidth=7;
final int boardHeight=7;
int totalMovesPlayed;

public BufferedReader input;
public char[][] board;

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Connect4Game();
}

public Connect4Game(){
    board = new char[6][7];
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    play PlayObj = new play();
    PlayObj.playGame();

    }
}
```

**play.java**

```
public class play extends Connect4Game {

public void playGame() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Connect 4");
    System.out.println("To play the game type in the number of the column you want to drop you counter in");
    System.out.println("Player One = r Player 2 = y");
    System.out.println("");


    board boardObj = new board();
    boardObj.printBoard();


    boolean win = false;
    while(!win){

        // player 1
        String userInput = getUserInput();
        int move = Integer.parseInt(userInput);

        counter counterObj = new counter();
        counterObj.placeCounter('r', move);


        boolean hasWon = false;
        int count = 0;

        // check horizontal
        for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++){
                if(board[i][j] == 'r'){
                    count = count + 1;
                    if(count == 4){
                        hasWon = true;
                        System.out.println("You Have Won!!!");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

        }

        // check vertical 
        count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<board[0].length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<board.length; j++){
                if(board[j][i] == 'r'){
                    count = count + 1;
                    if(count >= 4){
                        hasWon = true;
                        System.out.println("You Have Won!!!");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    count = 0;
                }
            }

        }
        boardObj.printBoard();
        if(hasWon){
            win = true;
            System.out.println("You Have Won!!!");
        }

        else {

            //player 2
            userInput = getUserInput();
            move = Integer.parseInt(userInput);


            counterObj.placeCounter('y',move);


            hasWon = false;
            count = 0;

            // check horizontal
            for(int i=0; i<board.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++){
                    if(board[i][j] == 'y'){
                        count = count + 1;
                        if(count >= 4){
                            hasWon = true;
                            System.out.println("You Have Won!!!");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }

            }

            // check vertical 
            count = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<board[0].length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<board.length; j++){
                    if(board[j][i] == 'y'){
                        count = count + 1;
                        if(count >= 4){
                            hasWon = true;
                            System.out.println("You Have Won!!!");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        count = 0; 
                    }
                }

            }
            boardObj.printBoard();
            if(hasWon){
                win = true;
                System.out.println("You Have Won!!!");
            }
        }

    }

}



public String getUserInput(){
    String toReturn = null;
    try{            
        toReturn = input.readLine();
    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
    return toReturn;
    }
}
```

**board.java**

```
public class board extends Connect4Game {

public void printBoard(){

    for(int i=0;i<board.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<board[0].length;j++){
            if(board[i][j] == 0)
                System.out.print(".  ");
            else
                System.out.print(board[i][j]+"  ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    for(int i=0;i<boardWidth;i++)
        System.out.print("*  ");
    System.out.println();

    for(int i=0;i<boardWidth;i++)
        System.out.print(i+"  ");
    System.out.println();
    }

}
```

**counter.java**

```
public class counter extends Connect4Game {

public void placeCounter(char player, int position){
    boolean placed = false;


    if(player == 'r'){
        for( int i=board.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(!placed && board[i - 1][position] != 'r' && board[i - 1][position] != 'y') {
                if(board[i][position] == 'y'){
                    board[i-1][position] = 'r';
                    placed = true;
                }

                else if(board[i][position] != 'r'){
                    board[i][position] = 'r';
                    placed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        for( int i=board.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            if (!placed && board[i - 1][position] != 'r' && board[i - 1][position] != 'y'){
                if(board[i][position] == 'r'){
                    board[i-1][position] = 'y';
                    placed = true;
                }

                else if(board[i][position] != 'y'){
                    board[i][position] = 'y';
                    placed = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The Connect4Game constructor calls new play(). play extends Connect4Game (why?), sothat calls the COnnect4Game constructor, which calls new play(), etc. etc. Don't extend classes that don't need to be extended. Respect tha Java naming conventions (classes start with an uppercase letter, variables with a lowercase letter). Don't start a game from a constructor.

Comment: The reason play extends Connect4Game is because of the board and input variables. If i dont extend, then the variables are unrecognised

Comment: That's not a valid reason to extend a class. Extending a class is used when the subclass **is a** superclass. For example, An Integer **is a** Number. A Banana **is a** Fruit. You don't just extend a class because it has some variables that you need to use. If Play needs a board and a reader, and can't create it by itself, then pass them as arguments to its constructor

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor for `Connect4Game` you are calling the constructor for the subclass `play` but that sub class does not have its own constructor so you are actually calling the same constructor for `Connect4Game` again, which then calls itself and so on until you have a stack overflow

```
public Connect4Game(){
  board = new char[6][7];
  input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  play PlayObj = new play();
  PlayObj.playGame();
}
```

Your main method should create a play object directly and then call the playGame method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    play PlayObj = new play();
    PlayObj.playGame()
}
```

And please follow java naming standards and have your classed start with an uppercase letter

Answer (score 3):

play extends Connect4Game.
So when you instantiate a new play object, this also calls the no-argument constructor of Connect4Game.
This Connect4Game() constructor instantiates a new play object which again instantiates a new Connect4Game. So you have made a recursive construction loop.

I think play should not extend from Connect4Game. A play instance is not a specific type of Connect4Game so extending it is not necessary/correct here.

In fact I don't think any of the other classes should extend from Connect4Game.

If you want the other classes to have access to the board and input variables, you should pass Connect4Game as a constructor parameter to these instances:

```
public class play {
    private Connect4Game connect;
    public play(Connect4Game connect) {
        this.connect=connect;
    }
    ...
}
```

in your code you can then use `connect.board` instead of just board.
Your main code becomes:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Connect4Game connect=new Connect4Game();
    play PlayObj = new play(connect);
    PlayObj.playGame();
}

public Connect4Game(){
    board = new char[6][7];
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
}
```

Your board class is difficult to read. Your class names should begin with a capital, instance variables with a lowercase character.

For your board class this could become:

```
public class Board {
    private Connect4Game connect;
    public Board(Connect4Game connect) {
        this.connect=connect;
    }
    // to refer to the board variable of Connect4Game:
    connect.board
}
```

Now you can ask yourself if you use this class Board ?